# Create a UDF function to decode a binary field "payload" based on its schema avsc

Tags: java, sql, apache-flink, avro, flink-sql

I have this schema of payload.avsc

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Data",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "guid",
      "type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": "long"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "name1",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "name2",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

here is my code juste to extracte the 2 field name1 and name2

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.avro.Schema;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord;
import org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder;
import org.apache.avro.io.DatumReader;
import org.apache.avro.io.DecoderFactory;
import org.apache.flink.table.functions.ScalarFunction;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class AvroDecoder extends ScalarFunction {

    private static Schema schema;

    public AvroDecoder() throws IOException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = AvroDecoder.class.getResourceAsStream("/payload.avsc")) {
            schema = new Schema.Parser().parse(inputStream);
        }
    }

    public payloadData eval(byte[] avroPayload) throws IOException {
        BinaryDecoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(avroPayload, null);

        DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
        GenericRecord genericRecord = reader.read(null, decoder);

        return new payloadData(
                
                genericRecord.get("name1").toString(),
                genericRecord.get("name2").toString()
                
        );
    }

 

    public static long[] convertByteBufferToLongArray(ByteBuffer byteBuffer) {
        byteBuffer.rewind();
        long[] result = new long[byteBuffer.remaining() / 8];
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            result[i] = byteBuffer.getLong();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static class payloadData {
        
        public String name1;
        public String name2;
        

        public payloadData( String name1, String name2 ) {
            
            this.name1 = name1;
            this.name2 = name2;
            
        }

       


        public String getName1() {
            return name1;
        }

        public String getName2() {
            return name2;
        }
    }
}
```

After that I created the jar file for this project so I can use it in my flink sql client code as

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION avro_decode AS 'com.example.AvroDecoder';

SELECT
  avro_decode(payload).name1 AS name1,
  avro_decode(payload).name2 AS name2
FROM tablekafka;
```

This function has been accepted in flink sql, but it doesn't show me any data, I think that there is a problem in the way that I made the code. Please, any help !